# Share variables between methods of the same class

Tags: python, oop

i've been trying to share a variable which is locally declared in one of the methods of the same class:

```
class test:

    def __init__ (self,a,b):

         self.a=a
         self.b=b

    def x(inputList):

         container = [test(x[0],x[1]) for x in inputList]

         for i in range (0,2):
               print("\n")
               print(container[i].a)
               print(container[i].b)
```

Consider:

```
xyz=[["abc","cde"],["fgh","ijk"],["lmn","opq"]]
```

I run:

```
test.x(xyz)
```

And the result is:

```
abc
cde


fgh
ijk


lmn
opq
```

Which is what I expected (the list "container" contains the objects from the class "test"). However, I'd like to access the "container" values in a another method of the class "test", for example:

```
def y():

    rst=container[2].a

    print(rst)
```

And i get the message Error:

```
NameError: name 'container' is not defined
```

Is there any workaround on this? Maybe some kind of Inheritance for methods...

I tried to use the following:

class test:

```
def __init__ (self,a,b,container):

    self.a=a
    self.b=b
    self.container=container

def x(inputList):

    container = [test(x[0],x[1]) for x in inputList]

    for i in range (0,3):
        print("\n")
        print(self.container[i].a)
        print(self.container[i].b)
```

However, when I try to run:

```
test.x(xyz)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'container'
```

I understand I'd have to change the passage:

```
container = [**test(x[0],x[1]**) for x in inputList]
```

Any guesses on that?

Comment: Either declare `container` as an attribute or, just pass it as a parameter to `y()`...

Comment: Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self|Class and Instance Variables"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)

Comment: In your `__init__` method do something like `self.container = []` and replace all uses of `container` with `self.container`

Comment: You seem to already understand instance attributes. Just use an instance attribute, or return `container` to the caller.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez, do you know how the syntax for it would be? I've tried some ways for both recommendations but without sucess...

Comment: You can't share local variables among different functions or methods (even methods of the same class) — that's what "local" means.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a `class attribute`, rather than anything "global" (which is one of the top "code smells").  Look up the topic and work through a tutorial including that language feature.

Comment: I'll try to follow the tutorial... I've added the option to include self.container. it doesnt work the way i wrote

Comment: @Prune: Mutable class state is every bit as bad as “true global variables” (especially since Python has only module attributes for the latter).

Comment: @Prune: Or maybe I misunderstood and you mean an instance (normal) attribute?

Comment: I think it would help if you would explain to us what you're trying to accomplish, rather than asking for help with a questionable implementation.  This is the "X/Y problem".

Comment: @Prune, I'm trying to use the variable "container" outside the method "x" or, as it seems this is not possible, to find a way I could run a method indicating the location of the file and, then, manipulate the data in order to be able to access the contents for other manipulations

Comment: Please resolve the references: "the file", "the data", "the contents".  This should be added to your question.  I'm still unclear about your overall goal; the higher-level solution depends on what you want this class to do for you.

Comment: @Prune, here it is: "the file" is a csv file which contains the 2 columns ("the data") which are being read by the for loop inside the container variable. "The contents" that I mentioned above is each line of "the data" being read. I would like to access the contents outside the method/class